# Performance of video stream processing in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, canvas, safari

I develop web application for mobile browsers which processes video stream from back camera in real time. Based on some calculated feature we may store current frame for followed operations.

The detailed workflow is next:

Input video stream in browser has 4K resolution. We use 3 canvases: two canvases have 4K resolution and the last one has significant lower resolution ( approximately 400x600 ). We get frame from video stream and draw it on 4K canvas. Next we draw this 4K canvas onto smallest one. Then we get array representation of image from this small canvas and  perform some calculation with it. Based on that calculation we decide if this frame should be stored or not ( we say that we found "Best frame" ). This best frame we store in original resolution 4K in the second 4K canvas for final processing and continue to process next frames in hope to fine little bit better.

In my work I faced with problem that Google Chrome shows less performance than FireFox on the same device and dramatically worse performance than Safari on the devices with same class.
In order to demonstrate the problem I created test html example. In it I use all of the operations which I consider as critical. There are: drawing frame from video stream onto first 4K canvas, scale this canvas and draw it onto smallest canvas, obtaining of array buffer from smallest canvas for calculation. These three operations are called for each frame therefore their performance is most critical for me.

[Repository with example](https://github.com/yekatkov/ChromeCanvasPerformance)

[Deployed example](https://flagellatecore.htmlpasta.com/)

[image: Results of my testing for different devices on different browsers]
Measured timers:
Execution time originalCanvas.drawFrame, ms - drawing of videoframe onto 4K canvas
Execution time scaledCanvas.drawFrame, ms - drawing 4K canvas onto small canvas
Execution time scaledCanvas.getBmpData, ms - obtaining byte array from small canvas
All big canvases in testing have resolution 3840x2160, all small ones have resolution 711x400.

Now let's move on to the most important thing... Why we have such big inequality in performance in different browsers and on different devices which have the same class? Unfortunately I can't test example in Chrome and FireFox on iPhones because of prohibition of access to camera there. I consider that manipulation with canvases is a simple operation which shouldn't be so long. And why Safari has extremely amazing performance compare with Chrome or even FireFox?

I hope my topic wasn't very boring. I would be glad to hear everything about my workflow in application or about my conclusions. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You realize you are comparing different devices not just the browser

Comment: Regarding the "fake calculation", there is something weird in Chrome indeed... The reduce should not take that long, but it seems they don't optimize it. Running a for loop is currently even slower (50ms), but on Canary a for loop will take a more reasonable 4ms, similar to Firefox's perfs. https://jsfiddle.net/pc4vo73t/ Regarding the getImageData call, that's [a known issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1001845). And then I should note that since the video streams you'll get will generally not have these dimensions, you are actually upscaling the images.